# Spring Security SAML Extension with Azure AD: SingleLogout problem

Tags: spring, azure-active-directory, saml, spring-saml

I have two web applications configured as SAML Service Providers, using version 1.0.10 of the Spring Security SAML extension. The identity provider is Azure AD.

Single sign-on across both applications works fine. The problem is with single logout (SLO). If I'm logged into both apps in two different browser tabs, and then initiate a logout from one app, that app is logged out as expected, but the logout of the other app fails.

With debug logging enabled, this is the output I get for the second app:

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - Securing GET /saml/SingleLogout?SAMLRequest=lZJfb5swFMW%2fCuLdYGPzxxZBypYtQ20aqVlbaS%2bRgUuKBjbFJs3HLwT1IdJUaW%2f2lY9%2b51yf1Miu7cW9PunRPsLbCMY6%2bWblHmscFoREGHHGJGJJTBHnCUYhl1SWUU1rWrrOMwym0WrlBh52ndyYEXJlrFR2GuEgQAQjQn8TKjATAfcinvxxnc1EaZS0V%2bWrtb0Rvt%2fKcYDW6wcwMJybUnql9sa%2f%2ftN03UklT9CBsv5s2D806tTC4tp1HrTdq%2f2wri0Mt1h2g710rTLimnjljoMSWprGCCU7MMKW4rDe3YspiOgHbXWpWzdLr5GGRfq1SJrJ6BzJzT4jGWu890ZV%2bt14CqwfSYkZqUrEo4IiFsoKceAFimKQAS4JgwT81F%2bYWfowMfKN81MPnbRfw%2bdJU6H6%2blT0868YO63L%2fU%2fnYfwcbrvzcWe%2f3R2L%2fO7Hmv%2b6BPtX%2fXLenrakfvveRo8o3B4anfqLvyxdOnQAM1chVxVcsiMNaREDo6jmkiBWQ4SSuJYowFUZTgcSYJz6%2f1B%2bDm8qmX0A&Signature=H2iMTbizxEM8ooIUfV%2fyZ8zZfkK8J9CXbVako2sPk9EUw1xjRUXfaCUbO3gpsjKvUD61UHEbpOexnMhCtqCJnItC81hIVp9dI2%2bSGqJ3%2fIYFtxDMqVAsP%2fxsEZpL%2f15OkZ0rj0n1nAiU7dT3xC0K5TDtjUWciKqbt0MkJgvKyvkZyjZGjhclfTGo4AJQrEkBVxkw8%2b2Evwgmxpk0taOfhq9sHaiRLzvVAxhCse9GZhbQehxyxtWWNDYt8Ks7JJJR5UDfdszX4E5J2576seSxvop3EeJLlULjjNm3FJZcXoKKAXzA%2bfHqYBYFD9rIyuEXaJsFEC0p8SSAHwKgDOq3PA%3d%3d&SigAlg=http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2f04%2fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - Securing GET /saml/SingleLogout?SAMLRequest=lZJfb5swFMW%2fCuLdYGPzxxZBypYtQ20aqVlbaS%2bRgUuKBjbFJs3HLwT1IdJUaW%2f2lY9%2b51yf1Miu7cW9PunRPsLbCMY6%2bWblHmscFoREGHHGJGJJTBHnCUYhl1SWUU1rWrrOMwym0WrlBh52ndyYEXJlrFR2GuEgQAQjQn8TKjATAfcinvxxnc1EaZS0V%2bWrtb0Rvt%2fKcYDW6wcwMJybUnql9sa%2f%2ftN03UklT9CBsv5s2D806tTC4tp1HrTdq%2f2wri0Mt1h2g710rTLimnjljoMSWprGCCU7MMKW4rDe3YspiOgHbXWpWzdLr5GGRfq1SJrJ6BzJzT4jGWu890ZV%2bt14CqwfSYkZqUrEo4IiFsoKceAFimKQAS4JgwT81F%2bYWfowMfKN81MPnbRfw%2bdJU6H6%2blT0868YO63L%2fU%2fnYfwcbrvzcWe%2f3R2L%2fO7Hmv%2b6BPtX%2fXLenrakfvveRo8o3B4anfqLvyxdOnQAM1chVxVcsiMNaREDo6jmkiBWQ4SSuJYowFUZTgcSYJz6%2f1B%2bDm8qmX0A&Signature=H2iMTbizxEM8ooIUfV%2fyZ8zZfkK8J9CXbVako2sPk9EUw1xjRUXfaCUbO3gpsjKvUD61UHEbpOexnMhCtqCJnItC81hIVp9dI2%2bSGqJ3%2fIYFtxDMqVAsP%2fxsEZpL%2f15OkZ0rj0n1nAiU7dT3xC0K5TDtjUWciKqbt0MkJgvKyvkZyjZGjhclfTGo4AJQrEkBVxkw8%2b2Evwgmxpk0taOfhq9sHaiRLzvVAxhCse9GZhbQehxyxtWWNDYt8Ks7JJJR5UDfdszX4E5J2576seSxvop3EeJLlULjjNm3FJZcXoKKAXzA%2bfHqYBYFD9rIyuEXaJsFEC0p8SSAHwKgDOq3PA%3d%3d&SigAlg=http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2f04%2fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter] - Delegating logout processing to super class...
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter] - Processing SAML logout message
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl] - Retrieving message using binding urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
INFO [org.opensaml.common.binding.security.BaseSAMLSimpleSignatureSecurityPolicyRule] - Validation of request simple signature succeeded
INFO [org.opensaml.common.binding.security.BaseSAMLSimpleSignatureSecurityPolicyRule] - Authentication via request simple signature succeeded for context issuer entity ID https://sts.windows.net/00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000/
INFO [org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule] - SAML protocol message was not signed, skipping XML signature processing
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil] - Found endpoint org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.impl.SingleLogoutServiceImpl@76b927ad for request URL https://server.com:443/app2/saml/SingleLogout?SAMLRequest=lZJfb5swFMW%2fCuLdYGPzxxZBypYtQ20aqVlbaS%2bRgUuKBjbFJs3HLwT1IdJUaW%2f2lY9%2b51yf1Miu7cW9PunRPsLbCMY6%2bWblHmscFoREGHHGJGJJTBHnCUYhl1SWUU1rWrrOMwym0WrlBh52ndyYEXJlrFR2GuEgQAQjQn8TKjATAfcinvxxnc1EaZS0V%2bWrtb0Rvt%2fKcYDW6wcwMJybUnql9sa%2f%2ftN03UklT9CBsv5s2D806tTC4tp1HrTdq%2f2wri0Mt1h2g710rTLimnjljoMSWprGCCU7MMKW4rDe3YspiOgHbXWpWzdLr5GGRfq1SJrJ6BzJzT4jGWu890ZV%2bt14CqwfSYkZqUrEo4IiFsoKceAFimKQAS4JgwT81F%2bYWfowMfKN81MPnbRfw%2bdJU6H6%2blT0868YO63L%2fU%2fnYfwcbrvzcWe%2f3R2L%2fO7Hmv%2b6BPtX%2fXLenrakfvveRo8o3B4anfqLvyxdOnQAM1chVxVcsiMNaREDo6jmkiBWQ4SSuJYowFUZTgcSYJz6%2f1B%2bDm8qmX0A&Signature=H2iMTbizxEM8ooIUfV%2fyZ8zZfkK8J9CXbVako2sPk9EUw1xjRUXfaCUbO3gpsjKvUD61UHEbpOexnMhCtqCJnItC81hIVp9dI2%2bSGqJ3%2fIYFtxDMqVAsP%2fxsEZpL%2f15OkZ0rj0n1nAiU7dT3xC0K5TDtjUWciKqbt0MkJgvKyvkZyjZGjhclfTGo4AJQrEkBVxkw8%2b2Evwgmxpk0taOfhq9sHaiRLzvVAxhCse9GZhbQehxyxtWWNDYt8Ks7JJJR5UDfdszX4E5J2576seSxvop3EeJLlULjjNm3FJZcXoKKAXzA%2bfHqYBYFD9rIyuEXaJsFEC0p8SSAHwKgDOq3PA%3d%3d&SigAlg=http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2f04%2fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256 based on location attribute in metadata
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter] - Received logout request is invalid, responding with error
org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLStatusException: No user is logged in
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl.processLogoutRequest(SingleLogoutProfileImpl.java:175) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:181) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.tessella.sdb.core.security.authentication.saml.SamlCustomLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout(SamlCustomLogoutProcessingFilter.java:52) [WebAppSecurity-6.6.0-bugfix_SUPPORT-1608-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:107) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
    ...
```

In Azure AD, the **Front-channel logout URL** for app2 is set as https://server.com/app2/saml/SingleLogout, so it looks like the endpoint is called & the HTTP-Redirect binding is used.

However, in SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter, for the line:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

auth is returned as null, i.e. there's no existing user session and so the logout fails. I've seen reports of this happening elsewhere with WSO2 as the SAML IdP, when the HTTP POST binding is used, but with Azure AD, my understanding is that this should be a front-channel request using the HTTP-Redirect binding.

Has anyone got Single Logout to work successfully using Azure AD as the IdP with the Spring SAML extension? Are there any configuration changes required either in the SP or IdP?

Any advice on what I need to do would be gratefully received. Thank you.

Comment: Is the user logged-in app2? If it's have you checked it auth is not null before logging out?

Comment: Hi @AlfredoRevilla-MSFT, thanks for the response - yes the user is logged in to app2. Given that they are logged in, what would set the auth to null, prior to the SingleLogout request being sent by Azure AD?

Comment: That's the question. Unless it was null from the beginning. Can you share more details about the enterprise apps, the SSO config, users and their claims expected and finally both java app authentication code/config?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found the answer. We're using the Apache web server as a reverse proxy in front of the apps, and this was setting same-site on the session cookie to Lax. Since the Logout request was coming from the SAML IdP, the session cookie was being removed. If same-site is set to None instead, the session cookie is attached, and the call to:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

returns the valid authentication credentials.